# How to assign two different variables to an object value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Not sure If my title makes sense but here's what I have problem doing.

I have two HTML outputs:

```
let output1 = `<h1>Header</h1>`
let output2 = `<div> // content </div>`
```

And I have this:

```
let mailOptions2 = {
      from: '"xyz" <xyz@info.com>', // sender address
      to: mailList, // receiver or receivers
      subject: 'XYZ', // Subject line
      html:       // html body
  };
```

I want both `output1` and `output2` assigned to `html`. I tried to put both in an array but it kept giving undefined error. So I want output1 be sent to the first address in mailList, and so on. Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to concat them:

```
html: output1 + output2
```

EDIT: With the updated requirement;

Put your variables in an array.

```
let output = [`<h1>Header</h1>`, `<div> content </div>`, ....]
```

Then create mailOptions variable inside a loop.

```
for(i = 0; i < mailList.lngth; i++) {
    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"xyz" <xyz@info.com>',
        to: mailList[i],
        subjects: 'XYZ',
        html: output[i] 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. But it puts the both html content on top of each other in the email client, which thats not what I want. I have two emails in mailList and it sends the email two both mail addresses. So I want output1 be sent to the first address in mailList, and so on, you got the idea.

Comment: @AhmetÖmer you should really consider putting that in the question. How is anyone supposed to know what you are trying to do if you don't put it in the question?

Comment: What do you mean? You want only output1 to be sent to the first address and only output2 to be sent to the second address?

Comment: Yes exactly that @KKK

Comment: Just added that part now as well @Mark_M

Comment: @AhmetÖmer Then you need to do that in a loop. or if the email addresses are constants, then you can do it with an if/ else

Comment: @AhmetÖmer I have updated the answer with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
outputs = ["1st HTML", "2nd HTML"];

for(var i = 0; i < mailList.length; i++){
    let mailOptions2 = {
        from: '"xyz" <xyz@info.com>',
        to: mailList[i],
        subject: 'XYZ',
        html: outputs[i % outputs.length]
    };
    // send your email here
}
```